# How to Find specific text in a formula in Multiple Columns (based on Column Header Names) and replace with different text

Tags: excel, vba

I am trying to make below code to work so that I can:

Find specific text "AMJ" in Formulas in specific Columns with
 Header Names: "RmRf" and "UMD"

Then once "AMJ" is found, it should be replaced with "ABC"

Most of the code that I have read (whilst searching for solution to above) use column numbers instead of column headers, but my worksheet will be updated every month, so column numbers will change and that's why I would like to use column header names (in this case "RmRf" and "UMD")

```
Public Sub FindAndConvert()
Dim i           As Integer
Dim lastRow     As Long
Dim myRng       As Range
Dim mycell      As Range
Dim MyColl      As Collection
Dim myIterator  As Variant

Set MyColl = New Collection

MyColl.Add "RmRf"
MyColl.Add "UMD"

lastRow = ActiveSheet.Cells.Find("*", SearchOrder:=xlByRows, SearchDirection:=xlPrevious).Row

For i = 1 To 2000
    For Each myIterator In MyColl
        If Cells(1, i) = myIterator Then
            Set myRng = Range(Cells(2, i), Cells(lastRow, i))
            For Each mycell In myRng.SpecialCells(xlFormulas)
                mycell.Formula = Replace(mycell.Formula, "AMJ", "ABC")
            Next
        End If
    Next
Next
End Sub
```

Comment: Why not just use [`Range.Replace`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.range.replace)? You have 3 loops, that's why your code takes so long to run.

Comment: Ok, so it looks like the above code actually works - but it took a very long time to run - I think over 15 mins and this does not make sense as I could have done a manual find and replace for the above two columns much more quickly. The two columns "RmRf" and "UMD" are columns ATF and  ATG in respectively in my sheet, so in above code I think I needed to use i = 1 To 2000 (as ATF is column number  1202 and ATG is 1203). Do you know what if anything can be done to achieve the same outcome but have the code run much faster (but still use Column Header Names)?

Comment: You don't need a loop at all. Use `Application.Match` to find the column by header.

Comment: Thank you for the Range.Replace suggestion. I am new to VBA, could I modify above code so that is uses Range.Replace or would I need to use a different code?

Comment: You'd have to get rid of the loop approach, so that would be a significant modification. But, as noted, you don't need to loop.

Comment: Thanks - I can see where the loops are in the code, so I can remove them, but I will need to do more research to try to figure out how to incorporate the Application.Match and Range.Replace suggestions so that I can make this work